# PHP object with soap XML identity claim property

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using PHP. I have an object that has a mobile phone as identity claim property. So my object looks like `{'http:schemas.cmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/dentity/claims/mobilephone': 1231231}`. What's the easiest way to get that property value?

I tried using curly bracket {} to access that property value, but no good.

Comment: that does not look like a php object. Is it a json string?

Comment: It looks like: object(stdClass)#1989 (1) { [" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/mobilephone "] => string(12) "111111111111"  } }

Comment: Although your object contains other punctuation rather than hyphens, the linked answers should work for your case as well: https://3v4l.org/EdSoq

Comment: @IMSoP yep that's another approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using get_object_vars and then accessing it as an array.